# How to resresh JFrame using thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel

I have a problem. I am creating JFrame where i give some numbers and after clicking "Accept" button, new JFrame should be opened. Then when I click "Start button", simulation starts, but what I want is to refresh this window. I want to refresh JLabels with values. It does not. I tried to do this by threads, but printing new values does not work. I think problem is in Thread3 and printValues method. What is wrong? Help!

Class Swing:

```
public class Swingg extends JFrame {
private String[] operations = {"starting money value", "upper Limit of warehouse", "lower Limit of warehouse", "starting amount of products of warehouse", "upper Limit of wholesale", "amount of items to delivery"};
private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[operations.length];
private Store store = new Store();

public void inputValues() {
    Box valuesLabels = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    Box valuesFields = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    for (String labels : operations) {
        valuesLabels.add(new Label(labels));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
        fields[i] = new JTextField(1);
        valuesFields.add(fields[i]);
        fields[i].setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(6));
    }

    JFrame inputWindow = new JFrame("Starting values");
    inputWindow.setSize(500, 400);
    JButton accept = new JButton("Accept");
    JPanel startingValuesPanel = new JPanel();
    startingValuesPanel.add(accept);
    JPanel inputValuesPanel = new JPanel();
    inputValuesPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30));
    inputValuesPanel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, valuesLabels);
    inputValuesPanel.add(BorderLayout.EAST, valuesFields);

    inputWindow.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, inputValuesPanel);
    inputWindow.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, startingValuesPanel);
    inputWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(inputValuesPanel);
    inputValuesPanel.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
    hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().addComponent(valuesLabels));
    hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().addComponent(valuesFields));
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);

    GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
    vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(valuesLabels).addComponent(valuesFields));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);

    inputWindow.setVisible(true);
    accept.addActionListener(e -> {
        double number1 = Double.parseDouble(fields[0].getText());
        store.setAccountBalance(number1);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(fields[1].getText());
        store.getWarehouse().setUpperProductLimit(number2);
        int number3 = Integer.parseInt(fields[2].getText());
        store.getWarehouse().setLowerProductLimit(number3);
        int number4 = Integer.parseInt(fields[3].getText());
        store.getWarehouse().setCurrentQuantity(number4);
        int number5 = Integer.parseInt(fields[4].getText());
        store.getWholesale().setUpperProductLimit(number5);
        store.getWholesale().setCurrentProductQuantity(store.getWholesale().getUpperProductLimit());
        int number6 = Integer.parseInt(fields[5].getText());
        store.getWholesale().setFillProductQuantity(number6);

        startSimulation();
        inputWindow.dispose();
    });
}
public void startSimulation() {
    JFrame simulationWindow = new JFrame("Simulation");
    simulationWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    simulationWindow.setSize(500, 300);
    simulationWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    simulationWindow.setVisible(true);

    Box warehouseLabels = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    Box wholesaleLabels = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);


    JPanel warehousePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel wholesalePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel moneyPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");


    store.fillWithProducts(store.getWholesale().products, 0.0, store.getWholesale().getCurrentProductQuantity());
    store.fillWithProducts(store.getWarehouse().storedProducts, 0.2, store.getWarehouse().getCurrentQuantity());

    moneyPanel.add(new Label("money: " + store.getAccountBalance()), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    for (Product product : store.getWarehouse().storedProducts) {
        warehouseLabels.add(new Label(product.getName() + ": " + product.getQuantity()));
    }

    for (Product product : store.getWholesale().products) {
        wholesaleLabels.add(new Label(product.getName() + ": " + product.getQuantity()));
    }

    buttonPanel.add(start);
    buttonPanel.add(exit);

    warehousePanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, warehouseLabels);
    wholesalePanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, wholesaleLabels);

    simulationWindow.add(moneyPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    simulationWindow.add(wholesalePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    simulationWindow.add(warehousePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    simulationWindow.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    exit.addActionListener(e ->
            System.exit(0)
    );

    start.addActionListener(e -> {
        Client sellingTask = new Client();

        //watek uzupelniania przedmiotow w magazynie
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // 10 seconds
                    sellingTask.buyProductsFromWarehouse(store);
                    //printValues(moneyPanel, simulationWindow);
                } catch (Exception e12) {
                    e12.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    store.fillMissingProducts();
                    printValues(moneyPanel);
                    Thread.sleep(25000); // 25 seconds
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    });
}

public void printValues(JPanel panel) {
    for (Component c : panel.getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) c).setText("money" + store.getAccountBalance());
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: *"new JFrame should be opened"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)